# extjs 4 grid in hbox does not appear

Tags: layout, extjs, hbox

I dont know what to do...
Without hbox the grid appears,
but with hbox not.

I added with & height and flex to each child element,
but it doesnt work...

Thanks in advance!

And here's the code:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.SimpleStore', {
        fields: [   'bMin', ], });   

    var myData = [ { "bMin": 10, } ];

    myStore.loadData(myData);

    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        layout : { type  : 'hbox', align : 'stretch', flex:2,
        Height: 150,
        Width: 300,
        },
        cls: 'custom-grid',
        store: myStore,
        columns: [

            {text: "bMin", dataIndex: 'bMin', type: 'float',},
        ],
        viewConfig: {
        emptyText: 'No records',
        forceFit : true,
        },
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    });

    var myPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        layout : {
        type  : 'hbox',
        align : 'stretch',
        },
        title: 'Hello',
        minHeight : 150,
        minWidth: 300,
        Height: 150,
        Width: 300,
        items: [
            grid,
            {xtype: 'button', width: 50, height: 50, flex: 1}
        ],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Grid you don't need a 'layout' config, also when using an HBox Height and Width is ignored on the child components so using flex is the way to go. I also added a 'pack' attribute to the hbox layout.

Try this:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.SimpleStore', {
        fields: [   'bMin', ], });   

    var myData = [ { "bMin": 10, } ];

    myStore.loadData(myData);

    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        flex: 1,
        cls: 'custom-grid',
        store: myStore,
        columns: [
            {text: "bMin", dataIndex: 'bMin', type: 'float',},
        ],
        viewConfig: {
        emptyText: 'No records',
        forceFit : true,
        },
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    });

    var myPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        layout : {
            type  : 'hbox',
            align : 'stretch',
            pack: 'start'
        },
        title: 'Hello',
        minHeight : 150,
        minWidth: 300,
        Height: 150,
        Width: 300,
        items: [
            grid,
            {xtype: 'button', flex: 1, text: 'test'}
        ],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```

JSFiddle Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vzURb/2/

Comment: it works :-) But i am facing a new problem... I got my grid on a hbox panel, sharing width with two more forms (labels for testing, but will take grids later). So when i dont use fixed width-values i can see only 4 columns. Hmm, i am just thinking about, that maybe the grid takes width of the whole window? Right now i got a window, containing 3 vbox container, and in the first vbox i got a hbox panel. First form inside is the grid, second a label, third also. I will take a look tomorrow at work, right now i can't

Comment: got it! I used `forceFit: true` on the grid without fixed width's cells. Now grid takes whole width of the panel to display

Comment: You can also add 'flex: 1' (or any number to change the percentage) to each column to make them all fit

Answer (score 0):

I see a number of problems here...

1. `height` and `width` config properties should not be capitalized
2. The `flex`, `height`, and `width` properties should all be on the panel itself, NOT on the panel's `layout`
3. The `flex` attribute will be weighted, so using `flex: 1` on your button and `flex: 2` on your panel will almost certainly not be what you are looking to do
4. You have `renderTo` on the grid, which is supposed to be inside your panel, so it should not use this config
5. You have commas at the ends of property lists, this can lead to lots of problems
6. You have `type` on a column, which is not a valid config
7. You don't need the layout on the `grid`

I can't tell exactly what it is that you want to do, but having an `hbox` layout with a button as the second `item` will look quite strange.  But, if that is what you are intending, this is probably more what you want:

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    cls: 'custom-grid',
    store: myStore,
    columns: [
        {text: "bMin", dataIndex: 'bMin'}
    ],
    viewConfig: {
        emptyText: 'No records',
        forceFit : true
    }
});

var myPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    layout : {
        type  : 'hbox',
        align : 'stretch'
    },
    title: 'Hello',
    height: 150,
    width: 300,
    items: [
        grid,
        {xtype: 'button', width: 50, height: 50, flex: 1}
    ],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```